# Rails 5 - ActiveRecord - Filtering has_many relation with includes and not exclude empty values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, eager-loading

Let me explain the title.

I have model A that has_many model B.

I want to filter model B by month and year of the date while showing all model A's

so for example:

A1 -> 3 Bs

A2 -> 0 Bs

A3 -> 1 B

This is my query right now:

```
A.includes(:b_relation)
 .where("extract(month from b.date) = #{month}").references(:b_relation)
 .where("extract(year from b.date) = #{year}").references(:b_relation)
 .all
```

It works! BUT it only gives me the A that has at least one B. The A's that have none don't show.

How can I make the query include the model A's that don't have any B's?

Answer (score 2):

The query you're doing now is using a `INNER JOIN` which will exclude records from `A` that have no associated `B`s. What you want instead is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`—aka a `LEFT JOIN`. Left joins include all rows from the parent table, whether or not there are any associated records from the associated table.

I always find this image useful for visualizing SQL join types:

[image]

Rails 5 has a `left_outer_joins` [method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActiveRecord%2FQueryMethods%3Aleft_outer_joins) for this (alias: `left_joins`):

```
A.left_outer_joins(:b_relation)
```

In earlier versions of Rails, it's more manual (I'm just making up the table names here):

```
A.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "bs" ON "bs"."a_id" = "as"."id"')
```

Comment: If I look at my query executed it does do a LEFT OUTER JOIN because internally includes will decide to use the 'eager_load' ActiveRecord method. It already uses the LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: Can you share the SQL being generated by your AR query?

Comment: Something like this

SELECT          "A"."id"                   AS t0_r0, 
               -- A COLUMNS
                "B"."id"                             AS t1_r0, 
               -- B COLUMNS
FROM            "A" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" 
ON              "B"."a_id" = "A"."id" 
WHERE           "A"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
 AND             "A"."blabla_id" = 'cfa7e8a8-5566-4ce7-bcbc-05cf420cf7d1'
 AND ((Extract(month FROM B.date) = 10) 
 AND (Extract(year FROM B.date) = 2017) OR B.date IS NULL)